# Best way to apply a function to content from a DataFrame column and save it in another

Tags: python, pandas

Hello everyone so here is the issue, I've got a DataFrame like this:

```
     item_id  item_title  item_content  title_trans  content_trans
0    1        "First"     "Stuff"       NaN          NaN
     ...      ...         ...           ...          ...
99   100      "Last"      "More stuff"  NaN          NaN
```

What i intend to do is apply a translation for the title and content column, saving the output to its respective last columns. (Translation will be done with TextBlob or python translate).
Output should look like this:

```
     item_id  item_title  item_content  title_trans  content_trans
0    1        "First"     "Stuff"       "Primera"    "Cosas"
     ...      ...         ...           ...          ...
99   100      "Last"      "More stuff"  "Última"     "Más cosas"
```

My latest idea was to make a for with DataFrame.iterrows(), and save each output with iloc, kinda like this:

```
for index, item in DataFrame.iterrows():
    raw_text = '\n'.join(item['item_title'], item['item_content'])
    trans_text = str(TextBlob(raw_text).translate(to='es'))
    title, content = trans_text.split('\n')
    DataFrame.iloc(index, 'title_trans') = title
    DataFrame.iloc(index, 'content_trans') = content
```

However good this is for small data sets, if i were to apply it to a massive one (thousands) i can see how it would start slowing down. Is there a way like to map it or a more efficent way to do it than a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `apply`:

```
df['title_trans'] = df['item_title'].apply(lambda x: str(TextBlob(x).translate(to='es')))
df['content_trans'] = df['item_content'].apply(lambda x: str(TextBlob(x).translate(to='es')))
```

Comment: nice, short and neat, I'll try it, think it could work regardless of dataframe size? or if its really too big should I segment it

Comment: Tried it but encountered an issue. While its working it rises an exception from TextBlob which meant it couldnt be translated, so the program gets interrupted.
Is there a way to circunvent the problem so it just saves the same text where the translation must have gone to?

Comment: found a solution, made a dedicated function to call with a try except structure. Thanks :D